# Jitpack.io is not working with sbt 1.0

Tags: sbt, jitpack

I have a Git project that runs with sbt 1.0.

I wanted to publish it with jitpack.io. But I get the following error:

```
Downloading sbt launcher for 1.0.2:
  From  http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt-launch/1.0.2/sbt-launch.jar
   To  /home/jitpack/.sbt/launchers/1.0.2/sbt-launch.jar
Download failed. Obtain the jar manually and place it at /home/jitpack/.sbt/launchers/1.0.2/sbt-launch.jar
```

`/home/jitpack` is a directory from jitpack.

Is there something that I can do in my project to make this work?

- Moving SBT to 0.13 works but is not what I want.
- Add something to the `build.sbt`.

Comment: How is jitpack related here? Does sbt-1.0 work in other projects? Is `/home/jitpack` your home directory? Add your project configs: `project/build.properties`, relevant parts of `project/*.sbt` and `build.sbt`.

Comment: thanks, no there was no reference to jitpack. I was wondering if I could influence that in my project by adding something. But it seems there is no possibility. see my answer

Comment: I'm glad that you found an answer, but I think you should still improve your question, clarify what is the context and the problem. Then it will be useful for others who may encounter it as well.

Comment: see my edit - I hope that makes my question clearer.

Comment: Great. You can also accept your own answer if it's definitive that it's blocked on Jitpack's side and there is no other solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround can be found here: https://github.com/jitpack/jitpack.io/issues/1887

You need create ".jitpack.yml" file and fill it with:

```
# workaround for https://github.com/jitpack/jitpack.io/issues/1887

jdk:
  - oraclejdk8
before_install:
   - wget http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt-launch/1.1.0/sbt-launch-1.1.0.jar
install:
   - java -jar sbt-launch-1.1.0.jar publishM2
```

Its worked for me

Comment: thanks I made it the correct answer - so I made a small change that your answer makes still sense

Answer (score 0):

I saw that this is really a bug in jitpack. And there is nothing I can do in my project configuration.

see: https://github.com/jitpack/jitpack.io/issues/1887